# Problem with WordPress "save_post" Action

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have developed a WordPress plugin which needs to perform additional processing when a post of a custom post type is saved.

The most logical solution was to utilise the "save_post" action. Upon being invoked the action handler either creates or updates a database record in a custom table (depending on whether "Create Post" or "Update Post" is clicked).

I have implemented this and it seemed to be working perfectly, but there is a minor issue which I would like to resolve. It seems that "save_post" is also triggered when loading the "Create Post" page for the first time (i.e. before any user inputs are entered and before the submit new/changes button is pressed).

This means that the custom database table is getting filled with one blank row for each new post that is saved. It also means that there is one blank row for each time the add post page is loaded.

Here is a simplified version of my "save_post" handler:

```
function do_save_post($post_id) {
    if (get_post_type($post_id) !== 'mycustomtype')
        return $post_id;

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;

    if (!current_user_can('edit_mycustomtype'))
        return $post_id;

    echo 'This happens when selecting "Add New" from admin sidebar.';
    echo 'Even though post has not been saved or updated.';
    echo 'This should only happen when button on right of editor is clicked.';
}
```

How can I detect whether the post is actually being saved?

Comment: what is the point of returning $post_id when it fails?

Comment: @helgatheviking It allows other hooks to perform their processing with the correct `$post_id`. My hook is not failing, it just wants to control when to undertake processing. The `$post_id` is passed from each hook to each hook by return.

Comment: @lea_hayes thanks for the reply! i didn't know the $post_id was passed from hook to hook. i haven't noticed any problems w/ code stalling if I don't return it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had this same problem and took a look at the relevant section of post.php.  Turns out save_post is called every time post.php runs, so you'll run it on post creation, list, etc.

In WP 3.1, "post_updated" is called only on a save/create event in post.php.  So I used:

```
add_action('post_updated', 'some_function');
```

Hope this works for you too.

Comment: Thanks, this is so close now. Is it possible to prevent it from triggering when the post is moved to trash?

Comment: This was easy for me actually, all I have to do is `if (!isset($_POST['my-extra-data'])) return $post_id;`

Comment: +1 This was really bugging me because it seemed to be creating a set of default values for all my fields, with all the checkboxes switched off.

Comment: Works only in case of updating post. Not after creating the post.

Answer (score 5):

Using the 'post_updated' hook tends to be problematic, particularly when using custom post types. Instead, I used this as my solution:

```
   function do_save_post($post_id){
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        if($post->post_status == 'trash' or $post->post_status == 'auto-draft'){
                return $post_id;
        }
        echo "do stuff";
    }
```

I didn't want to perform any actions when items were sent to the trash, either.

Answer (score 3):

This hook runs whenever a post or page is created or updated, which could be from an import, post/page edit form, xmlrpc, or post by email. So I'd guess it also runs when a post-revision is saved. If I where you I'd check if the postID is set (is the only argument the hook function should get) and if it is a revision `wp_is_post_revision()`.

Comment: `$post_id` contains a valid ID and `wp_is_post_revision()` doesn't appear to be of help. The hook is running as soon as "Add New" is selected from the admin sidebar. I have updated my original question with demonstration code to help elaborate on the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to just check if the data is actually being posted or not.

```
if(isset($_POST['post_title'])){
    //do stuff
}
```